# Error in fastapi while testing model 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'read'

Tags: python, numpy, fastapi

i have tried so many times but it's giving me error that numpy.ndarray object has no attribute'read' i am using cnn model for classifying two classes

```
app = FastAPI()

MODEL = tf.keras.models.load_model("models/16") #model saved with tensorflow save lib  

CLASS_NAMES = ["benign","malignant"]


@app.get("/ping")
async def ping():
return "Hello, I am alive"


def read_file_as_image(data) -> np.ndarray:
  image = np.array(Image.open(BytesIO(data)))
return image


@app.post("/predict")
 async def predict(
    file: UploadFile = File(...)
 ):
image = read_file_as_image(await file.read())
image = np.array(
    Image.open(image).convert("RGB").resize((256, 256))  # image resizing
)

image = image / 255
img_batch = np.expand_dims(image, 0)

predictions = MODEL.predict(img_batch)

predicted_class = CLASS_NAMES[np.argmax(predictions[0])]
confidence = np.max(predictions[0])
return {
    'class': predicted_class,
    'confidence': float(confidence)
}


if __name__ == "__main__":
   uvicorn.run(app, host='localhost', port=8000)
```

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'read'

Comment: There's an identation error in `read_file_as_image`, I assume the return statement is correctly indented in your actual code?

Comment: Same problem for `predict`. Please fix the indentation of your code so we can cut and paste it to try to reproduce it.

Comment: Now, your full stack track should explain the problem. You are passing an `ndarray` to the `file` argument of `predict`. I'm pretty sure that's not what you intended.